# Returning a result from multi-use dialog android

Tags: java, android

So in my android application, I have a helper class which can create a dialog box using the following code:

```
public void CreateAlert(String title, String message)
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

In my registrar activity, I have an ASyncTask that runs a particular task, following which it processes a boolean variable with the below function:

```
private void Process(boolean Success)
{
    if(Success)
    {               
        appHelper.CreateAlert("Success!", "Well Done!");

        // Progress to the activity
        startActivity( new Intent(context, Menu.class) );               
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    else
    {
        appHelper.CreateAlert("Failure!", "Please try again.");
    }
}
```

However as you can see from the above code, I am wanting to start an activity based on a succesful result. However, I need the application to wait for the user to click the okay button on the dialog before progressing to the next activity.

What is the best way for this to be done?

**EDIT:** I should note that the two functions are in different classes, CreateAlert is in a class called AppHelper where as Process is inside Registrar.class, an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again the status of boolean `success` in the click listener of alertDialog's `OK` button

```
    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    if(Success)
    {               
        // Progress to the activity
        context.startActivity( new Intent(context, Menu.class) );               
        context.getActivity().finish();
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't do anything
    } 
    });
```

and update your `Process` like below

```
private void Process(boolean Success)
{
    if(Success)
    {               
        appHelper.CreateAlert("Success!", "Well Done!");

     }
    else
    {
        appHelper.CreateAlert("Failure!", "Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2990037 Check the updated answer , you need to pass context of activity in the alertdialog class to start new Activity.

Comment: Sorry I don't think that solution will work :( void Process is in my main class and it needs to be able to find out when the OK button (listener registered in the apphelper class) has been pressed.

Comment: just try this it will work. tell me if you need any help in passing context.

Comment: Ah yeah, I can see what you mean now haha, Sorry its been a long day lol. I'm getting an error from getActivity(), its apparently undefined  for type Context. Also is there a way I can pass a class to CreateAlert?

Comment: yes you can, create a object instantiate it and pass as a parameter.